# Change the background of QR code to white

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I am quite new to php development. I am generating QR code through phpqrcode library. The code for this is written below and the output for it is shown in the attached image.

```
<?php
    include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    // outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream
    QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
?>
```

[image]

The problem is that the QR code appears in the black background on the screen and the center, whereas I need it to be in the white background and at the top right corner. I tried with the below-written code but it makes the QR code invisible as shown in the attached image.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:white">
            <?php
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
                $qr = new Endroid\QrCode\QrCode();
                $qr->setText('http://www.google.co.uk');
                $qr->setSize(100);
                $qr->setPadding(10);
                $qr->render();
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: php makes that qr code with gd package and not html or css! first read the doc, if there is no option to handle background, maybe you will need to edit php code and fill that with color code likes 255,255,255

Comment: it is interesting that the demo on their sf page creates qr codes with a white border... i was thinking that the issue is that the background is set to transparent?

Comment: Why aren't you using last version of `endroid/qr-code` (3.7.5)? Because this method is available only till version 1.9.3..

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that your are trying to render an image (`Content-Type: image/png`) inside an html response.

If you return only the image, it will be correctly shown.
You have to save the image inside a file, and then render it in html:

**Version 1.9.3**

```php
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php
                require 'vendor/autoload.php';
                $qr = new \Endroid\QrCode\QrCode();
                $qr->setText('http://www.google.co.uk')
                    ->setSize(100)
                    ->setPadding(10)
                    // In case you want to change colors
                    // RED foreground
                    ->setForegroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0]) 
                    // WHITE background
                    ->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0]);
                $qr->save('/qrcode.png');
            ?>
            <p>QR Image:</p>
            <img src="<?= 'qrcode.png'; ?>" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Version 3.7.5**

```php
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php
                require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                $qrCode = new \Endroid\QrCode\QrCode('http://www.google.co.uk');
                $qrCode->setSize(100);
                // Set advanced options
                $qrCode->setWriterByName('png');
                $qrCode->setMargin(10);
                // In case you want to change colors
                // RED foreground
                $qrCode->setForegroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0]);
                // WHITE blackground
                $qrCode->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0]);
                // Save it to a file
                $qrCode->writeFile( '/qrcode.png');
            ?>
            <p>QR Image:</p>
            <img src="<?= 'qrcode.png'; ?>" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```